# Assigning guide to graph's second value axis (amcharts)

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am able to assign guide line to graph's first value axis, but how to assign it second one?

I've tried by adding "valueAxis" in head of "guides":

```
"guides": [ {
            "valueAxis": "v2",
            "value": 0.1,
            "lineAlpha": 0.8,
            "lineColor": "#c00",
            "label": "Guide #1",
            "position": "right"
            }]
```

where "v2" is id of my second value axis, from:

```
"graphs": [{
          "valueAxis": "v2"....
```

No luck.

Comment: Post a fiddle. [It works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/gp4ezb2d/4/)

Comment: Oh man @xorspark thanks a lot for your example! With the help of your fiddle i realized that i were adding `guides` as child element into `graphs` node. So simple `guides` block move one level up (at the same level as `graphs`) - solved my problem! If you want, you can write the answer, i will mark it.

Comment: You're welcome! I posted a more fleshed out answer.

Comment: @xorspark it's a little unrelated question, but still about multiple graphs on single chart (Amchart) and guide. Now i have overlapping column chart with guideline which hides behind columns. Is there any option to bring it to front (https://imgur.com/a/HNUDF) ?

Comment: The only way to bring guides in front of the graphs is to set [`gridAboveGraphs`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#gridAboveGraphs) to true. Note that this will also affect your axis grid lines as well. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gp4ezb2d/11/)

Comment: @xorspark perfection, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippet looks right but make sure your properties are set up correctly. `guides` can either be a child of the [chart object](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#guides), a child of a [Value Axis](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#guides) object or a child of the [Category Axis](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#guides) object. As you found out, it isn't a graph property.

Comment: Yes, i realized that i were adding guides as child element into graphs node. So simple guides block move one level up (at the same level as graphs) - solved my problem!  Thanks.